# React Material UI select capture reference intead of Event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem using material select.I want to Capture the whole object in onChange() function. Current event is only capturing the selected value. For Example : If I select Status 'IN PROGRESS', I want to capture STATUS_CODE of that Object.

```
class ExmComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          status:'Open' ,
      };
    const statusList = [
{
  "STATUS_ID": 10,
  "STATUS": "Open",
  "STATUS_CODE": "OSNO",
  "LINK": "open",
  "ICON": "done_outline"

},
{
  "STATUS_ID": 20,
  "STATUS": "In Progress",
  "STATUS_CODE": "NOPR",
  "LINK": "inProgress",
  "ICON": "play_arrow"
},
{
  "STATUS_ID": 40,
  "STATUS": "Cancelled",
  "STATUS_CODE": null,
  "LINK": "cancelled",
  "ICON": "cancel_presentation"
},
{
  "STATUS_ID": 30,
  "STATUS": "Closed",
  "STATUS_CODE": "NOCO",
  "LINK": "closed",
  "ICON": "close"
}
];
```

event.target.value only returns the value.
  Here I want to Capture the whole Object
  Example If closed is selected, I want to capture the whole closed Object

```
  /* {
          "STATUS_ID": 30,
          "STATUS": "Closed",
          "STATUS_CODE": "NOCO",
          "LINK": "closed",
          "ICON": "close"
      }*/
    handleChange = event => {
          this.setState({status: event.target.value});

      };

      render(){
          return(
          <Select
              select
              label="Status"
              value={status}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
              {statusList.map(option => (
                  <MenuItem key={option.STATUS_ID} value={option.STATUS}>
                      {option.STATUS}
                  </MenuItem>
              ))}
          </Select>
          )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you filter out the full object from the "statusList" array in handleChange function?
Something like this:

```
  handleChange = event => {
    const fullObject = statusList.filter(val => event.target.value === val.STATUS)[0];
    console.log(fullObject);
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/2zy7m2701r

Comment: I can use filter.But, there is any other way to do it?